# Delete all letters from String

Tags: kotlin

How can i delete all letters from String?
I've got given String:

```
val stringData ="ABC123.456"
```

Output value:

```
val stringData ="123.456"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try regex replacement here:

```kotlin
val regex = """[A-Za-z]+""".toRegex()
val stringData = "ABC123.456"
val output = regex.replace(stringData, "")
println(output)  // 123.456
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim Biegeleisen. That's it what i wanted